# How to deal with this double integral $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\int_0^tdx\int_x^t\sin(x^2y^2)dy}{t^6}$

Tags: integration, limits

I try to take derivative:$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\int^t_t\sin t^2y^2dy}{6t^5}$,but upper limit and lower limit are both $t$，

Comment: welcome to MSE, what have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please explain what have you tried for solving this equation. Also it seems there is an error in the question, the bounds of integral are the same.

Comment: Question has errors!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\int^t_0dx\int_x^t(sin(x^2y^2))dy}{t^6}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\int^t_0dx\int_x^t(x^2y^2)dy}{t^6}\\=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\int^t_0 x^2* 1/3y^3|_{y=x}^t dx}{t^6}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\int^t_0 1/3*(t^3x^2-x^5) dx}{t^6}=\frac{1}{18}$$

Comment: please avoid answering no effort questions

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) regarding quality standards.